# Intellij idea (12.1.4) does not highlight matching variables

Tags: text, intellij-idea, ide, matching, highlighting

Intellij idea does not highlight matching variables for me.

Check following image.

[image]

Editor settings for IDE

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I set highlighting matching variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, can I recommend you [BrowseWordAtCaret plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201?pr=idea) ?